# How can i fully output an item of the class with Console.Writeline?

Tags: c#, properties

I have this class:

```
public class JsonIntProperty
{
    private string characteristic;
    private int age;
    
    public JsonIntProperty(string chr, int agee)
    {
        characteristic = chr;
        age = agee ;
    }
    
    public string StringRepresentation
    {
        get { return $"{characteristic} : {age}"; }
    }
}
```

I create an instance of this class with

```
var ageProperty = new JsonIntProperty("age", 21);
```

How do I use my object to print "age : 21" to the console? I've tried

```
Console.WriteLine(ageProperty)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *use* the `StringRepresentation` property when you want to print to the Console.

```
var ageProperty = new JsonIntProperty("age", 21);
Console.WriteLine(ageProperty.StringRepresentation);
//                            ^^^ this
```

Otherwise you're printing the name of the type.

Alternatively, you can override ToString.

```
public class JsonIntProperty
{
    // ...
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // pick one of the following:
        return $"{characteristic} : {age}";
        // OR
        return StringRepresentation;
    }
}
```

```
var ageProperty = new JsonIntProperty("age", 21);
Console.WriteLine(ageProperty);
//                      ^^ no StringRepresentation here
```